# How to write a whole LaTeX document in bf?

Tags: fonts

How to write a whole LaTeX document in bold? I would like to print the pdf in bfseries. Is this possible to achieve by adding some code to the preamble or in the body of the LaTeX document?

Comment: just put `\bfseries` after `\begin{document}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think `\renewcommand\seriesdefault{b}` in the preamble should better match what OP intends. Funny thing is that this way you still get a visual difference between `text` and `\textbf{text}`, as the latter uses `bx` by default.

Comment: @Skillmon I was keeping it simple... (but yes)

Comment: I've used before the package `pdfrender` to make the generated PDF font more bold, without changing the actual font in Latex.  Do not know if this meets your requirements or not.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 16):

## pdfLaTeX answer

The optimum depends somewhat on the used font. For Computer Modern (the default font in LaTeX), there are no bold italics, only bold extended italics. So the optimum depends whether you're using `\textbf` to highlight things or `\textit`. If you're using `\textbf` then the best approach would be to use

```latex
\renewcommand\seriesdefault{b}
```

in your preamble. If however you're using `\textit` or `\itshape` in your document the usage of `b` as the series would result in no italics at all, as LaTeX would detect that `b/it` (bold italic) is not available and would use `b/n` (bold upright) instead. So if you want `\textit` and `\itshape` to work as expected you'd have to use

```latex
\renewcommand\seriesdefault{bx}
```

in your preamble.

In complete examples:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\renewcommand\seriesdefault{b}

\begin{document}
Text (normal).

\textbf{Text (bold)}.

\textit{Text (italic)}.

\textit{\textbf{Text (bold italic)}}.
\end{document}
```

Results in

[image: result using b]

And

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\renewcommand\seriesdefault{bx}

\begin{document}
Text (normal).

\textbf{Text (bold)}.

\textit{Text (italic)}.

\textit{\textbf{Text (bold italic)}}.
\end{document}
```

Results in

[image: result using bx]

However, if you by chance use a font that has both `b/it` and `bx/it`, then `\renewcommand\seriesdefault{b}` should be the best choice.

---

### Using `kpfonts` as an example

The `kpfonts` family has a wide coverage of series and shape combinations (there might be others, but currently (2019-10-12) this happens to be my favourite font). The funny thing about `kpfonts` is that it comes in a light and a standard variant, and you can use both the light and the standard variant in combination if you specify the `rmx` option. So with `kpfonts` you have different viable combinations:

1. Using `b` and `bx`:

   ```latex
   \documentclass[]{article}

   \usepackage{kpfonts}

   \renewcommand\seriesdefault{b}
   \renewcommand\bfdefault{bx} % just to make sure

   \begin{document}
   \begingroup
   \usefont\encodingdefault\familydefault{m}\shapedefault\relax
   Text (really normal), which would be used normally
   \endgroup

   Text (normal).

   \textbf{Text (bold)}.

   \textit{Text (italic)}.

   \textit{\textbf{Text (bold italic)}}.
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Using `sb` and `b`

   ```latex
   \documentclass[]{article}

   \usepackage[rmx]{kpfonts}

   \renewcommand\seriesdefault{sb}
   \renewcommand\bfdefault{b}

   \begin{document}
   \begingroup
   \usefont\encodingdefault\familydefault{m}\shapedefault\relax
   Text (really normal), which would be used normally
   \endgroup

   Text (normal).

   \textbf{Text (bold)}.

   \textit{Text (italic)}.

   \textit{\textbf{Text (bold italic)}}.
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Of course you could also combine `sbx` and `bx` or `sb` and `bx` or however you like.

Answer (score 12):

## LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX answer: Use the fontspec package

After loading the `fontspec` package, modify the arguments of the `\setmainfont` directive to specify **Bold** and ***BoldItalics*** as the default font shapes.

And, if needed, modify the arguments of the `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont` instructions to obtain **Bold** and ***BoldItalics*** as the default font shapes for sans-serif and mono-spaced (aka "typewriter") font families.

This approach is not as challenging as it may seem like at first: If you're using the `fontspec` package, you may already have an instruction such as

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[%
             ItalicFont=Times New Roman Italic,
             BoldItalicFont=Times New Roman BoldItalic]
```

in the preamble of your document. All you'll need to do, then, is add "Bold" in two places:

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman Bold}[%
             ItalicFont=Times New Roman BoldItalic,
             BoldItalicFont=Times New Roman BoldItalic]
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%% Choose suitable font families and weights. E.g.:
\setmainfont{Times New Roman Bold}[%
             ItalicFont=Times New Roman BoldItalic,
             BoldItalicFont=Times New Roman BoldItalic]
\setsansfont{Helvetica Bold}[Scale=MatchLowercase,
             ItalicFont=Helvetica Bold Oblique]
\setmonofont{Consolas Bold}[Scale=MatchLowercase,
             ItalicFont=Consolas Bold Italic,
             BoldItalicFont=Consolas Bold Italic]

% pangram:
\newcommand\qbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
\qbf
\textit{\qbf}
\sffamily
\qbf
\textit{\qbf}
\ttfamily
\qbf
\textit{\qbf}

\medskip
\rmfamily\bfseries
Explicit \texttt{\textbackslash bfseries} --- exactly the same as above:
\qbf 
\textit{\qbf}
\sffamily
\qbf
\textit{\qbf}
\ttfamily
\qbf
\textit{\qbf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr - You're right. I'll update my answer accordingly.